# Xamarin.android Notification onClick doesn't take to new activity

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, android-notifications, altbeacon

This is going to be a long post! (grab a cup of coffee/popcorn)

I am using [AltBeacon](https://github.com/chrisriesgo/Android-AltBeacon-Library) Xamarin sample in my code to show the beacons.

I have come across [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/local_notifications_in_android/#Starting_an_Activity_from_a_Notification) example in creating Notifications in Xamarin.

Here there's an Application class where the core logic goes.

```
public class AltBeaconSampleApplication : Application, IBootstrapNotifier
{
    private const string TAG = "AltBeaconSampleApplication";

    BeaconManager _beaconManager;

    private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
    private Region _backgroundRegion;
    private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;
    private bool haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot = false;

    private string nearbyMessageString = "A beacon is nearby.";
    private string nearbyTitleString = "AltBeacon Reference Application";

    private MainActivity mainActivity = null;
    public MainActivity MainActivity
    {
        get { return mainActivity; }
        set { mainActivity = value; }
    }

    private NotificationActivity notificationActivity = null;

    public NotificationActivity NotificationActivity
    {
        get { return notificationActivity; }
        set { notificationActivity = value; }
    }

    public AltBeaconSampleApplication() : base() { }
    public AltBeaconSampleApplication(IntPtr javaReference, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer) { }


    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        _beaconManager = BeaconManager.GetInstanceForApplication(this);

        var iBeaconParser = new BeaconParser();
        //  Estimote > 2013
        iBeaconParser.SetBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24");
        _beaconManager.BeaconParsers.Add(iBeaconParser);

        Log.Debug(TAG, "setting up background monitoring for beacons and power saving");
        // wake up the app when a beacon is seen
        _backgroundRegion = new Region("backgroundRegion", null, null, null);
        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, _backgroundRegion);

        // simply constructing this class and holding a reference to it in your custom Application
        // class will automatically cause the BeaconLibrary to save battery whenever the application
        // is not visible.  This reduces bluetooth power usage by about 60%
        backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);

        PerformHttpRequest();
    }

    public void DidDetermineStateForRegion(int state, AltBeaconOrg.BoundBeacon.Region region)
    {
    }

    public async void PerformHttpRequest()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var uri = "http://exampleuri";
                var result = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
                var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BeaconURL>(result);
                SendNotificationFromBeacon(response);

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }            
    }

    private void SendNotificationFromBeacon(BeaconURL receivedNotification)
    {
        // Setup an intent for SecondActivity:
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(NotificationActivity));

        // Pass some information to SecondActivity:
        notificationIntent.PutExtra("CompaignUrl", receivedNotification.CompaignUrl);
        notificationIntent.PutExtra("MediaUrl", receivedNotification.MediaUrl);
        notificationIntent.PutExtra("titleText", receivedNotification.Title);
        notificationIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

        // Create a task stack builder to manage the back stack:
        Android.App.TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = Android.App.TaskStackBuilder.Create(this);

        // Add all parents of SecondActivity to the stack: 
        stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(NotificationActivity)));

        // Push the intent that starts SecondActivity onto the stack:
        stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(notificationIntent);

        // Obtain the PendingIntent for launching the task constructed by
        // stackbuilder. The pending intent can be used only once (one shot):
        const int pendingIntentId = 0;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(pendingIntentId, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        // Instantiate the builder and set notification elements, including 
        // the pending intent:
        var builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .SetContentTitle(receivedNotification.Title)
                .SetContentText(receivedNotification.Text)
                .SetSmallIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcDialogInfo);

        // Build the notification:
        Notification notification = builder.Build();

        // Get the notification manager:
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
            GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

        // Publish the notification:
        const int notificationId = 0;
        notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);
    }
}
```

**BeaconURL** is a **POCO** class
**NotificationActivity** is a basic **Activity** class.

I perform the HttpClient request and get data. I create a notification and present it on my screen. It goes like this
[image]

Now when I tap on the notification, I dont go to the NotificationActivity. I am trying to invoke an activity from an ApplicationClass. Is this the right way to perform such stuff. Kindly provide details.

Thanks.

**Edit**: Added NotificationActivity Class

```
[Activity(Label = "NotificationActivity")]
public class NotificationActivity : MainActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.NotificationLayout);

        TextView titleTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtTitle);
        titleTextView.Text = Intent.Extras.GetString("titleText", "");

        ImageView mediaImage = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgViewMedia);
        mediaImage.SetImageBitmap(GetImageBitmapFromUrl(Intent.Extras.GetString("MediaUrl", "")));
    }

    private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
    {
        Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
            if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
            {
                imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            }
        }

        return imageBitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the `ParentActivity` name set in the `Activity` attribute on your `NotificationActivity` activity (or the correct entires in the manifest if you are manually assigning a `Name` in the `Activity` attribute?)

Comment: NotificationActivity class is subclass to Activity, I have added the code for the same class. Can you kindly look into it @SushiHangover. Thanks

Comment: I was talking about the `[Activity(....)]` attribute on that class, not the class itself.

Comment: This is set to [Activity(Label = "NotificationActivity")]

Comment: Since you are not setting `ParentActivity` in that attribute, are you setting it in the manifest?

Comment: Have added ParentActivity to MainActivity, yet this doenst seem to be working @SushiHangover

Comment: Following. I have a similar problem although I'm not using notifications but broadcastreceiver instead. But my activity opens if in fore or background, only not if closed. Check my code to see if anything helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45810508/how-wake-up-device-and-show-an-activity-on-top-of-lock-screen-for-alarm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to do is to set the your pending intent within the notification builder, it will get your `NotificationActivity` launching:

```
var builder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .SetContentTitle("receivedNotification.Title")
        .SetContentText("receivedNotification.Text")
        .SetSmallIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcDialogInfo)
        .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

The second will be to get your back stack setup, from what you posted I'm not sure what the flow should be as the user will exit the app if they use the back button.

If you want the user to go back to the `MainActivity` when that press the back button, then you can add a `ParentActivity` to your `NotificationActivity` activity attribute, i.e.:

```
[Activity(Label = "NotificationActivity", ParentActivity = typeof(MainActivity))]
```

And thus the line:

```
stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(NotificationActivity)));
```

Would add the `MainActivity` to the back stack.

Comment: This missing piece
SetContentIntent(pendingIntent) did the trick. Awesome!